# How to pass AWS secret key and id in jenkins build pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to pass the AWS secret key and password into jenkins script (which creates the env file)

My code:

```
node {

    writeFile file: 'temp_env.txt', text: """
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY= << Access Key >>
    AWS_SECRET_KEY= << password >>
  """
docker.withRegistry('https://quay.io', 'c5234316dc-dqwqwda1-415645452-b343-406bf8332edb') {

        sh 'docker pull quay.io/docker_image'
        docker.image ('quay.iodocker_image').run('-it --env-file temp_env.txt --name test quay.io/docker_image:develop ./code/test1.py test-service')
        sh 'rm temp_env.txt'
    }
}
```

I am using the actual secret key and id, i would rather have the credentials injected here. How can I achieve it? I read the entire instructions [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) but was not able to figure out.

I know how to use the credentials binding plug-in, but not sure how I can add the user_name and password credentials variables to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of [those instructions](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) is to first store those credentials in the [Credentials section of Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#configuring-credentials), from the [Jenkins Credential Biding plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding), as [shown here](https://www.coveros.com/securing-jenkins-when-using-aws/)

[image: https://www.coveros.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/blog_jenkins_cred_accesskey.png]

Once there are safely stored there, you can declare them in an environment step:

```
environment {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-key-id')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('jenkins-aws-secret-access-key')
}
```

Comment: I don't see an option to Bind the variables. Where should I define jenkins-aws-secret-key-id and jenkins-aws-secret-access-key

Comment: @Ravi See https://www.coveros.com/securing-jenkins-when-using-aws/ as an example. If you have the credentials binding plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) installed, you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** The best practice for storing credentials, api tokens and secret keys is to store it on **global credentials** in jenkins ( this applies to all scope of credentials in the project/item/object) and get it pipeline code. This methodology prevents users storing sensitive data in plain-text insecurely on their code/project.

> I'll demonstrate it with **short example**: On this example I'll store an api token of my app in Jenkins credentials ,get it in my pipeline step and curl it to perform some rest api HTTP operation on my server.

**First** Store it:

> Jenkins -> Credentials -> Global -> Add Credentials -> Select your
>   type and fill in the details

[image]
In my example I create secret text with secret xxx, the ID would be MY_SECRET_TOKEN and the description would be my secret token for my api service. **Than** I'll save it and my pipeline would be like below...

```
script{
   withCredentials([
      string(
         credentialsId: 'MY_SECRET_TOKEN',
         variable: 'TOKEN_VARIABLE')
      ]) {
      sh """#!/bin/bash
         curl -k -L -H 'Authorization: Token ${TOKEN_VARIABLE}' 
         https://myservice/api/users/someaction/
      """
  }
}
```

For more information look on the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/)

Comment: is there any API where if I want to update the TOKEN_VARIABLE and store it back in Jenkins credentials ?

Comment: Why I echo the variable, output "***", but not the real value ?